# No match for operator++ in stl_tree.h even though i haven't changed it

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

i got my code working without errors in main.cpp, but suddenly, i get this error:

```
/opt/lintula/gcc/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/stl_tree.h:2223: error: no match for ‘operator++’ (operand type is ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’)
  for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
                            ^
```

I haven't touched the stl_tree.h, why is the error happening there? How can i debug these kinds of problems when i don't know where to start?

Here's the code, where im trying to read and insert data in form of 
name:points into a std::map

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   map<string, string> piste_hakemisto;
   string input_tiedosto;
   cout << "Input file: ";
   cin >> input_tiedosto;
   ifstream tiedosto_olio(input_tiedosto);
   if (not tiedosto_olio){
       cout << "Error! The file " << input_tiedosto << " cannot be opened.";
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   string nimi;
   string pisteet;
   string rivi;
   while( getline(tiedosto_olio, rivi)){
       getline(tiedosto_olio, rivi);
       int erotin_indeksi = rivi.find(":");
       nimi = rivi.substr(0, erotin_indeksi);
       pisteet = rivi.substr((erotin_indeksi));
       piste_hakemisto = {nimi, pisteet};
   }

}
```

Comment: That is most likely not the only error you got. Maybe the first one, but somewhere in that stream of errors is a reference to your file.

Comment: Yes, it is not the only error, but i cannot find any references to main.cpp, there's an error in function.h and stl_iterator_base_types.h

Comment: Did you mean to write `piste_hakemisto[nimi] = pisteet;` instead of _`piste_hakemisto = {nimi, pisteet};`_?

Comment: john gave me a good solution for the problem. I previously received obscure error messages from QT, don't know why but now it seems to work with map::insert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you start with the last piece of code you added. Which I'm guessing is this

```
piste_hakemisto = {nimi, pisteet};
```

That should be

```
piste_hakemisto.insert({nimi, pisteet});
```

(other ways of doing the same thing are also possible).

It's a common problem with templates, the error messages are often obscure and refer to code deep within the template definition.